# MS-Word: Word field to restart Heading list count

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I know that for custom sequence I can use {SEQ dummy \r 0}.
Moreover, the sequence itself can start depending on the specified Heading: {SEQ dummy \s 2}.

I'm looking for a field which will start the counting of the Heading style.
It will have the same behavior as right click on the number and select "Restart at 1".

Is there such an option?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a built-in option to do that. What can be done is a VBA macro that scanned the document's Heading styles and then restarted any custom sequence field(s) that are associated with the Headings.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this option.. It's a nasty one.